# How to stop floating menu at bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, menu, scroll, jquery-animate

Im using this script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#menu_border").offset();
        var topPadding = 20;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#menu_border").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#menu_border").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It makes my $menu_border following the window as the user scrolls. The problem is, I have a div "under" this one and when the user (with a screen of lesser resolution then 1080) scrolls to the bottom of the page, this script just keeps on pushing #menu_border down, making the page longer and longer.

So the question is; Is there a simple way to make it stop at a certain point? The best thing would be inside a container (#container_div in this case).

Hope I made myself understood.

Best regards!

Comment: If you always want `menu_border` to be at the same place with respect to the browser window why not adding `position:fixed` to css?

Comment: Because I want it to slide into fit at the top and bottom, that wont be possible with fixed. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop adding to the margin the moment value of `$(window).scrollTop()` combined with height of the #menu_border exceeds height of the body.

This one is of top of my head, and I didn't try it live, but altering your first condition to be:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top && 
    ($(window).scrollTop() + $('#menu_border').outerHeight() <=  $('BODY').height()) {
```

instead of

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top)
```

should do the trick. Depending on whether you have padding on #menu_border you're maybe want to use `$('BODY').outerHeigh()` instead of `$('BODY').height()`.

Let me know if you did it.